# Matchstick Problem: Turn 1 into 12 by removing a matchstick

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, matches

Below are some matchsticks arranged to display an expression.

Your task is to remove one matchstick so that the resulting value of the expression will be twelve.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear. Remove--- not Move right?

Comment: There are so many possibilities...

Comment: I love how many answers the people on this group have come up with to what is essentially an impossible problem!

Comment: There seem to be a *lot* of different answers here, and no reason to particularly prefer any of them. (Several of the other answers seem more plausible than the accepted one.)

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks,but I did not accept the answer just because I preferred it. I only accepted it because it was what I had in mind in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Remove the top of the 7. The 8 can be viewed as 13, so $13-1= 12$. Which also means that you can make it equal to $13-7=6$ without moving any matches!

Demonstration:

> [image]

Comment: "Without moving any matches" yet you had to move two matches to make it work!

Comment: Next puzzle: Turn 8 into 13 without touching anything

Answer (score 24):

Here is another fairly lateral one:

> [image]
>  
>  If we interpret "-" as difference of shapes then the result is a small "c" which is, of course, the hexadecimal for 12.

Comment: difference of shapes, hexadecimal, you seem to have very flexible interpretation of the assignment ;-)

Comment: @TMS Don't say flexible, please. I prefer the word "lateral" ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Possibly a little too lateral but if we

> Remove the middle match from the '8' to make a '0'

And then

> Look at the image inverted

We get

> [image]

which could be interpreted as

> **L - 0 = L** and since **L** is position **12** in the alphabet, this can be interpreted to evaluate to **12**.

Comment: But, but, but... if the left is an L shouldn't the right be an O (the letter, not the digit)?

Comment: I also had this idea, but usually people would use $A$ for $10$, $B$ for $11$, etc.

Comment: @WhatsUp Actually, my first inclination would be that L=50

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nah man, it's clearly a 0.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it the more I like it. The "-0" does a decent job of killing the L=50 association. This almost resembles something intentional ;-)

Answer (score 6):

A bit of a stretch, but here goes:

> [image]
>  
>  The only way to read the thing on the left as a number is as a 1 and a 9 who haven't heard about social distancing rules. So that will read 19-7.

Comment: It just looks like an "A" to me

Comment: @bobble Just squint a bit ;-) --- I said it was a bit of a stretch. And I wouldn't have posted this if the other answers were any more compelling.

Comment: So your final result is $3$... Also you don't have to remove any stick to read it as $19$.

Comment: @WhatsUp The point is that with the bottom in place there is no reason at all to read it as anything but an 8. With the stick removed I can't think of any plausible way of reading this as a  number other than the one I suggest.

Comment: You could read it as "1 - 7" just as easily as "19".

Comment: @chepner _"easily"_ ?!? I take your point, though.

Comment: The implication being "19" isn't entirely obvious, either.

Comment: I was just tickled by your innovative use of the word "easy", @chepner, that's all. As I said I fully take your point. Besides, one could also say that bobble's take "[0x]A" is no less cogent than either "19" or "1-7". I'll be happy to admit that this answer is a bit of a stretch. Oh, wait, already did that ;-)

Answer (score 5):

My answer is

> Invert the image
>  Remove the match which is (now) bottom right
>
>  [image]
>
>  This leaves two characters `L` and `@`
>  In ASCII encoding, the difference in their values is $12$
>
>  Similar to other answers, but "sticks" to a single coding scheme.

Answer (score 3):

> Remove the lower-left stick on 8.
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

> Japanese borrowed the English word *dozen* as ダース (dāsu). Remove the bottom left match and you get:

> `_    _
>     |_| _  |
>     | |    |`

> which is ダース in a rather crappy low resolution font (especially the *su* is really ugly)

Comment: That can by no means be read as a ス. Anybody would rather call it a フ. Also you are missing the two dots, which are crucial. So basically you created a [ターフ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95)

Comment: @RadovanGarabik Cool!

Answer (score 0):

My swing at it:

> Remove the middle bar from the 8. It’s now D hexadecimal. Minus 1 is C which is 12 base 10.

Answer (score 0):

> In very lateral thinking, let "remove one matchstick" be interpreted as  "re-move one matchstick", which means to move one matchstick again. So move the top right matchstick to the windowsill. Then re-move it to the middle of the puzzle so it reads B + 1, which in hexadecimal is 11 + 1, which is 12.

Answer (score -1):

> Remove the middle stick on the left.  Then you get "0 - 7" which equals 12 (mod 19).

Comment: Can't understand how this is correct if we are taking mod $19$ like that way.

Comment: @Anonymous Minus seven is congruent to twelve mod 19.

Comment: It is, but why are we considering mod? in that case I would solve most of the matchstick problems like this, taking mod of a certain number, in this case, 19

Answer (score -2):

> Move a stick from 8 and place it over '-' to make a '+'. [image]

> Next remove a stick as shown to get 5+7=12. [image]

Comment: If you are are allowed a preprocessing step, you could simply rearrange the matchsticks all you like before removing one.